# Datomic aggregations: counting related entities without losing results with zero-count

Tags: datomic, datalog

I have a domain model made of Questions, each Question being associated with a number of Comments and Affirmations.

I would like to make a [Datalog query](http://docs.datomic.com/query.html) which extracts a bunch of content attributes for each Question, as well as the number of associated Comments and Affirmations, **including when these relationships are empty** (e.g some Question has no Comment or no Affirmation), in which case the returned count should be 0.

I have seen the following [Gist](https://slack-redir.net/link?url=https%3A%2F%2Fgist.github.com%2Fvvvvalvalval%2F5547d8b46414b955c88f), which shows how to use `(sum ...)` and `(or-join)` combined with a 'weight' variable to get a zero-count when the relationship is empty.

However, I do not see how to make this work when there are 2 relationships. I tried the following, but the returned counts are not correct:

```
(def query '[:find (sum ?comment-weight) (sum ?affirmation-weight) ?text ?time ?source-identifier ?q
             :with ?uniqueness
             :where
             [?q :question/text ?text]
             [?q :question/time ?time]
             [?q :question/source-identifier ?source-identifier]
             (or-join [?q ?uniqueness ?comment-weight ?affirmation-weight]
               (and [?comment :comment/question ?q]
                 [?affirmation :affirmation/question ?q]
                 ['((identity ?comment) (identity ?affirmation)) ?uniqueness]
                 [(ground 1) ?comment-weight]
                 [(ground 1) ?affirmation-weight])
               (and [?comment :comment/question ?q]
                 [(identity ?comment) ?uniqueness]
                 [(ground 1) ?comment-weight]
                 [(ground 0) ?affirmation-weight])
               (and [?affirmation :affirmation/question ?q]
                 [(identity ?affirmation) ?uniqueness]
                 [(ground 1) ?affirmation-weight]
                 [(ground 0) ?comment-weight])
               (and [(identity ?q) ?uniqueness]
                 [(ground 0) ?comment-weight]
                 [(ground 0) ?affirmation-weight]))])
```

*Originally asked on the Clojurians Slack.*

Answer (score 4):

So to summarize, the trick is to consider each Question, Comment and Affirmation as a 'data point', which has a 'weight' of 0 or 1 for each count, and is identified uniquely (so that Datalog counts correctly, see `:with`). In particular, each Question has a zero weight for all counts.

The posted code was almost correct, it only needs to remove the first clause of the `(or-join ...)`, which results in creating 'artificial' data points (Comment + Affirmation tuples) that pollute the counts.

The following should work:

```
[:find (sum ?comment-weight) (sum ?affirmation-weight) ?text ?time ?source-identifier ?q
 :with ?uniqueness
 :where
 [?q :question/text ?text]
 [?q :question/time ?time]
 [?q :question/source-identifier ?source-identifier]
 (or-join [?q ?uniqueness ?comment-weight ?affirmation-weight]
   (and 
     [?comment :comment/question ?q]
     [(identity ?comment) ?uniqueness]
     [(ground 1) ?comment-weight]
     [(ground 0) ?affirmation-weight])
   (and 
     [?affirmation :affirmation/question ?q]
     [(identity ?affirmation) ?uniqueness]
     [(ground 1) ?affirmation-weight]
     [(ground 0) ?comment-weight])
   (and 
     [(identity ?q) ?uniqueness]
     [(ground 0) ?comment-weight]
     [(ground 0) ?affirmation-weight]))]
```

Comment: this works. thank you! I'm still not totally clear on why it works though. i was under the impression that or-join would return the first match for each ?q - wouldn't that mean that when there is a :comment/question and an :affirmation/question that only the comment would be counted? i think i'm still not grokking how :with works

Comment: No, think of or-join as a set union - not as the boolean OR

Answer (score 1):

You can call arbitrary functions within a query, so consider using `datomic.api/datoms` directly (or a subquery, or an arbitrary function of your own) to count the comments and affirmations.

Using `datomic.api/datoms`:

```clj
'[:find ?comment-count ?affirmation-count ?text ?time ?source-identifier ?q
  :where
  [?q :question/text ?text]
  [?q :question/time ?time]
  [?q :question/source-identifier ?source-identifier]
  [(datomic.api/datoms $ :vaet ?q :comment/question) ?comments]
  [(count ?comments) ?comment-count]
  [(datomic.api/datoms $ :vaet ?q :affirmation/question) ?affirmations]
  [(count ?affirmations) ?affirmation-count]]
```

Or using a subquery:

```clj
'[:find ?comment-count ?affirmation-count ?text ?time ?source-identifier ?q
  :where
  [?q :question/text ?text]
  [?q :question/time ?time]
  [?q :question/source-identifier ?source-identifier]
  [(datomic.api/q [:find (count ?comment) .
                   :in $ ?q
                   :where [?comment :comment/question ?q]]
     $ ?q) ?comment-count-or-nil]
  [(clojure.core/or ?comment-count-or-nil 0) ?comment-count]
  [(datomic.api/q [:find (count ?affirmation) .
                   :in $ ?q
                   :where [?affirmation :affirmation/question ?q]]
     $ ?q) ?affirmation-count-or-nil]
  [(clojure.core/or ?affirmation-count-or-nil 0) ?affirmation-count]]
```

Or using a custom function:

```clj
(defn count-for-question [db question kind]
  (let [dseq (case kind
               :comments (d/datoms db :vaet question :comment/question)
               :affirmations (d/datoms db :vaet question :affirmation/question))]
    (reduce (fn [x _] (inc x)) 0 dseq)))

'[:find ?comment-count ?affirmation-count ?text ?time ?source-identifier ?q
  :where
  [?q :question/text ?text]
  [?q :question/time ?time]
  [?q :question/source-identifier ?source-identifier]
  [(user/count-for-question $ ?q :comments) ?comment-count]
  [(user/count-for-question $ ?q :affirmations) ?affirmation-count]]
```

Comment: Given the current fixed overhead of `datomic.api/q`, I would be careful with the subquery approach.

Comment: using datomic.api/datoms i'm seeing: UnsupportedOperationException count not supported on this type: db$datoms$reify__2144 
                                                                                   clojure.lang.RT.countFrom (RT.java:646)

Comment: This error is because `datoms` returns an Iterable, on which `count` is not supported. Maybe you can work around that by coercing them using `(seq)`, or use a custom function.