# How to sum values including entities with missing attributes on Datalog/DataScript/Datomic

Tags: clojure, datomic, datalog, datascript

I'm learning Datalog/DataScript/Datomic. For this I've setup a simple ledger database on DataScript to play with. By now it basically consists of a set of accounts and a list of records with the attributes `:entry.record/account` and `:entry.record/amount`. Now I'm trying to get the balance of all the accounts, by summing all the `:entry.record/amount` for each account. This query gives me the balance for all the accounts **that have records** on the ledger:

```
  (d/q '[:find ?account ?account-name (sum ?amount)
     :with ?record
     :in $
     :where [?account :account/name ?account-name]
            [?record :entry.record/account ?account]
            [?record :entry.record/amount ?amount]]
   @conn)
```

But I have some accounts that still doesn't have any record registered, and they don't appear here. I want to make a query that includes them, listed with 0 value. I've been playing with `or-join` and `missing?` to include those accounts on the query but I have no clue on how to get the amount to 0 for the accounts. For example, this query:

```
  (d/q '[:find ?account ?account-name (sum ?amount)
     :with ?record
     :in $
     :where [?account :account/name ?account-name]
     (or-join [?record]
              (and [?record :entry.record/account ?account]
                   [?record :entry.record/amount ?amount])
              [(missing? $ ?record :entry.record/account)])]
   @conn)
```

Throws an exception with the message `Query for unknown vars: [?amount]` since the second part of the `or-join` can't assign a value to `?amount`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Datomic's Datalog is definitely uncomfortable for this sort of aggregation; my recommendation is indeed to use or-join so as to emit a zero amount:

```
[:find ?account ?account-name (sum ?amount)
 :with ?sum-term
 :in $
 :where [?account :account/name ?account-name]
 (or-join [?account ?amount ?sum-term]
   (and
     [?sum-term :entry.record/account ?account]
     [?sum-term :entry.record/amount ?amount])
   (and
     [(identity ?account) ?sum-term]
     [(ground 0) ?amount]))]
```

See also: [Datomic aggregations: counting related entities without losing results with zero-count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47417009/datomic-aggregations-counting-related-entities-without-losing-results-with-zero/47417128#47417128)

Comment: It works perfectly, but it's somewhat tricky. As I understand, you use `identity` to give some binding to the free-var `?sum-term`. I've tested it by also using `(group 0) ?sum-term` and it gives the same results. Is there any issue with using `group` instead of `identity`?

Comment: @Peluko I assume you meant `(ground 0) ?sum-term` ? That seems to work fine, but I personally find it less regular semantically, which might make the code harder to read.